# why is it so hard to run simple spark streaming ? spark 1.1.1 Maven dependency

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming, It was working fine when i was using spark1.0.2, now i repeatedly getting few issue

Like class not found, i am using the same pom.xml with the updated version for all spark modules 
i am using  spark-core,streaming, streaming with kafka modules..

Its constantly keeps throwing errors for no commons-configuation, commons-langs, logging

**How to get all the dependencies for running spark streaming.. Is there any way or we just have to find by trial and error methord?**

my pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency> <!-- Spark streaming dependency -->
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after wasting a lot of time i have arrived at the answer.

1.Make sure your spark version and version in your pom is same
2.Hadoop version of the spark is the version with which spark is build or use spark hadoop prebuild version
3.Update your spark env .sh with required details

```
export JAVA_HOME=/User/java/
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=xyz
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4g
export MASTER=spark://${SPARK_MASTER_IP}:${SPARK_MASTER_PORT}
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=xyz
```

4.If you are using maven and eclipse use m2e 1.5 version or else you are bound to get log4j exception.
5.Make sure you clean compile package your jar file every time before you code submit your spark application

Answer (score 1):

Your pom.xml still uses spark-core version 1.0.2. Please use version 1.1.1 for all spark-related dependencies in pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Have updated my pom with latest version, however i keep getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils for diff jars

Comment: Now i am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder but i have added slf4j-log4j12 in dependency.. Not sure what should i do now.. any pointers..tried giving scope as runtime also no luck

Comment: make sure you submit a fat jar with all dependencies included.

Comment: i am including all the jars, also i am getting invalid class exceptions

Comment: Good. Can you check your log4j version and spark/hadoop's lig4j version?